# Continuous animation function with close

Tags: jquery

Erm, little hard to explain so I'll keep it simple (plus I've been up for 24 hours :O)

the idea is, you mousein on parent and it's image bounces. I want the bounce to be continuous until mouseout event. I'm trying to get better with jQuery so I'm trying this:

```
$.fn.bounce=function(){
    return this.each(function(){
        var self=this;
        this.original=$(this).css('position');
        if(this.original!='relative')$(this).css({'position':'relative'});
        //Not sure if using queues would be better? 
        $(this).animate({top:-20},200);
        $(this).animate({top:0},100);
        $(this).animate({top:-10,}100);
        $(this).animate({top:0,}50);
        $(this).animate({top:-5},25);
        $(this).animate({top:0},0,function(){$(this).css({'position':self.original});
    });
};

$('#parent').mousein(function(){$('img','#parent').bounce();});
```

How can I make the animation continue until mouseout? :S I'm lost and don't even know where to start looking DX

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is this:

declare a flag `bouncing=false`
on `mouseover` (not `mousein`), set the flag to `true` and run a function which bounces forever *as long as* `bouncing===true`

on  `mouseout`, set the flag to false

**JS**

```
var bouncing = false;
var bounce = function () {
    //upward animation for .1 sec
    $('#parent').find('img').animate({top: "55px"}, 100, function () {
        //downward animation for.1 sec
        $(this).animate({top: "95px"}, 100, function () {
            if (bouncing === true) {
                //keep bouncing if the flag is set
                return bounce();
            } else {
                //otherwise we are done bouncing
                return true;
            }
        });
    });
};
$('#parent').mouseover(function () {
    //if we are already bouncing, do nothing
    if (bouncing === true) {
        return false;
    } else {
        //else set the flag true, and start bouncing!
        bouncing = true;
        bounce();
    }
});
$('#parent').mouseout(function () {
    //stop bouncing on mouse out
    bouncing = false;
});
```

**CSS**

```
#parent{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    border:2px solid black;
    border-radius:4px;
    position:relative;
}
#parent > img{
    position:absolute;
    top:75px;
    left:75px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id=parent>
    <img src=someimg.jpg>
</div>
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/qvsyjqec/

Thats the basic idea, you could make it more robust by adjusting the animation speeds, messing with easing/keyframing, or a number of other things